# How to Find similar data with different Rowid in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rowid

I have a table like this:

```
X   Y
======
20  20
20  20
20  21
23  22
22  23
21  20
```

I need to find those rowid's  where `X=Y` but their rowid is not the same? Like 1st row's `X` and 2nd row's `Y` is the same but they are in different rows.

Comment: ``ROWID`` never be same for two different row in query result

Comment: Which `ROWID` values do you want in your output?  For example, the value `20` has multiple matching pairs of records with a different `ROWID`.  What values do you want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Suppose the rowid for each row is 11,12,13 ... and i want 11 because 11'th X = 12'th Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it many ways, and since you brought the `rowid` up, this is one of them:

```
select * from yourtable tab1 join yourtable tab2 on tab1.x = tab2.y and tab1.rowid <> tab2.rowid
```

Answer (score 0):

You want duplicate rows:

```
select *
from
 (
   select x, y, rowid, count(*) over (partition by x,y) as cnt
   from tab
   where x=y
 ) dt
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works

```
  select * from tab a where exists (select * from tab b where a.x=b.y and a.rowid!=b.rownid);
```

Comment: It's saying for rownum
invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Comment: ROWNUM is a pseudocolumn produced as rows are output from a query - it is not a column in a table. Perhaps you meant ROWID?